# Execute cmd command from VBScript

Tags: cmd, vbscript

How I can Execute a `cmd` command from VBScript (not by .bat file)

For example, I want to execute the following from VBScript:

```
cd /d C:dir_test\file_test 
sanity_check_env.bat arg1
```

Comment: you mean **execute** dos commands from VBScript?

Answer (score 11):

To run 'dos' commands you need to instantiate the `WScript.Shell` object and use it's `Run()` method:

```vb
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd cd /d C:dir_test\file_test & sanity_check_env.bat arg1"
```

Answer (score 3):

Create WScript.Shell object and invoke Run() method on it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Can also invoke oShell.Exec in order to be able to read STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR responses. Perfect for error checking which it seems you're doing with your sanity .BAT.