# How to launch System File Checker tool with vbs

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, wsh

In batch or cmd, sfc.exe run with a simple command:

```
%windir%\system32\SFC.exe /SCANNOW
```

How to run this command with .vbs script (x86 x64)??

Thanks

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467818/execute-dos-command-from-vbscript) but nothing

Comment: Please add your code to this post. No one is going to open a foreign link on SO.

Comment: Hi ragingasiancoder. I did not put the code because I have too many codes, different places, and none works. I'm sorry, but I can not fill my question with useless codes.

Comment: We're not asking for _all_ your code. The best way to get help here, is to provide a [mcve]. You can [edit] it into your question. Good luck!

Comment: No way barth. Solved by hackoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, just give a try !

```
Option Explicit
' Run as Admin
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
    , WScript.ScriptFullName & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
    WScript.Quit
End If
Dim ws,MyCommand,Execution
Set ws = createobject("wscript.shell")
MyCommand = "SFC /SCANNOW"
Execution = ws.run(MyCommand,1,False)
```

Comment: hi hackoo. look at [this questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38535724/fix-vbs-to-launch-hide-system-file-checker). thanks