# fix vbs to launch hide System File Checker

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd

I have this vbs (part of the script was provided by [hackoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509033/how-to-launch-system-file-checker-tool-with-vbs)) to launch sfc.exe to fix system files, but like I need to add some features, such as a message, and I need while running sfc.exe, display a message "wait" (hiding the sfc.exe window) and the end of the program, exit the final message, but the script does not work well (sfc.exe fails hiding the window and displays the final message before concluding)

```
Option Explicit
 ' Run as Admin
  If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
 , WScript.ScriptFullName & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
WScript.Quit
End If
On Error Resume next
mensaje = MSGBOX ("Start System File Checker", vbOKCancel, "System File Checker")
If mensaje = vbOK Then
Dim ws,MyCommand,Execution
Set ws = createobject("wscript.shell")
MyCommand = "%windir%\system32\SFC.exe /SCANNOW"
Execution = ws.run(MyCommand,1,False)
objshell.run NewPath,vbhide
CALL MSGBOX ("System File Checker has finished", VBOKONLY, "System File Checker")
Else
CALL MSGBOX ("System File Checker has been canceled", VBOKONLY, "System File Checker")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Note: missing part "wait" while running hidden sfc.exe

Thanks

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line `objshell.run NewPath,vbhide` There's no reference to objshell or NewPath

Comment: And this `Execution = ws.run(MyCommand,1,False)` isn't waiting for return - so it's doing exactly what you're telling it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the console you should write it like that :

Change `False` to `True` for waiting until the process will finish and the value `1` to `0` to hide the console

```
Execution = ws.run(MyCommand,0,True)
```

And your code should look like this one :

```
Option Explicit
' Run as Admin
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
    , WScript.ScriptFullName & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
    WScript.Quit
End If
Dim ws,MyCommand,Execution,Question
Question = MSGBOX ("Did you want to start the System File Checker ?", vbOKCancel+vbQuestion, "System File Checker")
If Question = vbOK Then
    Set ws = createobject("wscript.shell")
    MyCommand = "%windir%\system32\SFC.exe /SCANNOW"
    Execution = ws.run(MyCommand,0,True)
    If Execution = 0 Then
        Call MSGBOX ("System File Checker has finished", VBOKONLY, "System File Checker")
    Else
        Call MSGBOX ("System File Checker has been canceled", VBOKONLY, "System File Checker")
        Wscript.quit(1)
    End If
Else 
    Call MSGBOX ("System File Checker has been canceled", VBOKONLY, "System File Checker")
    Wscript.quit(1)
End If
```

Comment: Very good hackoo, but lacks the part of "Wait ..." while running hidden sfc