# Compiling error whenever i type "@echo of" in VBscript

Tags: windows, vbscript

When I type in `@echo off` in VBscript I get an error:

[image: The error I get when I type @echo off]

How can I fix that?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? How are you running your VBScript and what is being echoed that you don't want to be echoed?

Answer (score 4):

`@echo off` is native to batch files. VBScript can execute batch commands, see here: [Execute DOS command from VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467818/execute-dos-command-from-VBScript) But what you are asking makes no sense on its own, as VBScript is essentially a separate entity from batch scripts.

If you want to echo text from a VBScript, you could do something like

```
WScript.echo("line to echo")
```

in your VBScript and call it from your batch file with

```
cscript yourscript.vbs
```

and then use `@echo off` in your batch file, but without any information as to why you are trying to do this it is impossible to give you a more direct answer.